# Rest API URL Convention for fetching resource

Tags: rest, api

I am confused regarding creating URL for Rest API.

In our System, we are storing prices for version and city combination. Multiple version maps to model.

So data for price will be like:
Version|City|Price
12 |23| 300000
13 |23| 400000
14 |25| 350000

So data for version will be like:
version | Model 
12 | 5
13 | 6
14 | 5

Below two problem we are trying to solve.

Problem 1: need to fetch price for version = 12 and city = 23
Problem 1: need to fetch price for model = 5 and city = 23

what should be rest convention URL for problem1 and problem2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query parameters to supply search conditions.
Like this

Problem 1:   GET /price?version=12&city=23

Problem 2:   GET /price?model=5&city=23

http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#advanced-queries